# Animation Button css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do an `css` animation on a button, to move from left to right and right to left (quickly), then stop and do the same action again.

**HTML and Style**

```css
button {
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation: mymove infinite;
  /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  -webkit-animation-duration: 6s;
  /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  animation: mymove infinite;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}


/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */

@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
  from {
    left: 0px;
  }
  to {
    left: 10px;
  }
}

@keyframes mymove {
  from {
    left: 0px;
  }
  to {
    left: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<button>value</button>
```

i tried this, but i'm not satisfied, any suggestions please ? what i want is to move the button very quickly from the left to right and stops then move again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to can i use - https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation - and this statistic : https://clicky.com/marketshare/global/web-browsers/safari/, i think you do not need prefix.

Anyway, you can use percentage instead of "to" and "from", so you can be very specific.

```css
button {
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  animation: mymove infinite 3s;
}


@keyframes mymove {
   0% {left: 0px;}
  10% {left: 10px;}
  70% {left: 10px;}
  100% {left: 0px;}
}
```

```html
<button>value</button>
```

Comment: it moves very queckly.., i want to take the attention of the user when the user see it, u know what i mean?

Comment: I don't understan what you want to do anyway. It's really weird to make a button moves to infinity.  Because when a user will try to click on it the button could move at this time, some the user miss the button. Don't you have more code or design to send us ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `keyframes` percent to handle your events, like this:

```css
button {
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    animation: mymove infinite;
    animation-duration: 10s;
}

/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
    0% {
        left: 0%;
    }

    50% {
        left: 100%
    }

    100% {
        left: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<button>value</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want this [examle](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_animation-direction) ?

```css
button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation: myfirst 5s 2;
  /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
  /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  animation: myfirst 5s 2;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}


/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */

@-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
  0% {
    background: red;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  25% {
    background: yellow;
    left: 200px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  50% {
    background: blue;
    left: 200px;
    top: 200px;
  }
  75% {
    background: green;
    left: 0px;
    top: 200px;
  }
  100% {
    background: red;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
  }
}

@keyframes myfirst {
  0% {
    background: red;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  25% {
    background: yellow;
    left: 200px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  50% {
    background: blue;
    left: 200px;
    top: 200px;
  }
  75% {
    background: green;
    left: 0px;
    top: 200px;
  }
  100% {
    background: red;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="button">go</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

With keyframes you can use % instead of `from` and `to`

with this you have more control on the timing part.

[More info](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can use % values in the keyframes.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rL9qw48k/)

```css
button {
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  animation: mymove infinite;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

@keyframes mymove {
  0% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  1% {
    left: 10px;
  }
  2% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  98% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  99% {
    left: 10px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<button>
  value</button>
```

Comment: it moves very queckly.., i want to take the attention of the user when the user see it, u know what i mean?

Comment: @Newme Sorry, I don't fully understand. If you want to slow it down just change the `animation-duration` property.

Answer (score 0):

Try these and change in ***margin-left: 50px;***  for increase or decrease Movement area..

```css
button {
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation: mymove infinite;
  /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  animation: mymove alternate infinite;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  50% {
    margin-left: 50px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<button>value</button>
```